# How does List.RemoveAt(index) work?

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a list, messages, with three items. I wan't to loop through them and remove one item at a time.

```
for (int i = 0; i < messages.Count; i++)
{ 
    messages.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

(I've removed lots of irrelevant code)

What happen to the remaining messages after the first iteration? Are they moved to another index or can I do it like this to remove all three messages?

Thank you

Comment: No offense, but have you actually tried running your code? It would have taken less time than asking this question I guess.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that while I was typing. But my code is a bit more complex than this so I figured it is easier to ask. And it may help others too. Answers on SO are easier to understand than reading the MSDN pages. @DominicKexel

Comment: MSDN help seems pretty clear: `When you call RemoveAt to remove an item, the remaining items in the list are renumbered to replace the removed item. For example, if you remove the item at index 3, the item at index 4 is moved to the 3 position. In addition, the number of items in the list (as represented by the Count property) is reduced by 1.`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The index of all elements behind the index you remove will be decremented.
If you want to avoid this with your loop let it run in reverse (delete from highest index to lowest).

```
for (int i = messages.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{ 
    messages.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

or just use

```
messages.Clear()
```

to delete all elements at once without taking care about any indices.

If you just want to clear the List it's also more efficient to use `Clear` since it is a O(n) operation. `RemoveAt` is O(n) as well but inside another O(n) loop which makes it O(n^2) - not that it would matter with 3 elements as mentionend in your example but when talking about larger lists it would certainly make a difference.

Comment: Thank you. Like I said, I want to loop through all elements, so the .Clear() is not something I can use. I still like the explanation though.

Answer (score 5):

In your code, it's simpler to just call `messages.Clear();`. There's no need to remove each element separately.

Your code will skip every other element as it removes them until the `for` loop's conditional is no longer met. It will remove the elements at indexes 0 and 2 because you said your collection has three elements.

Let's step through your algorithm:

Initially, the list has three items, listed with their indexes: 0: "Hello", 1: "World", and 2: "Foo".

Your loop removes the element at index 0. The list now looks like this:

0: "World", 1: "Foo"

However, your loop executes again, since `i` now equals 1 and `1 < 2`. The element at index 1 is then removed:

0: "World"

`i` is incremented to 2 and the conditional is no longer met (`i` is not less than 1). Your list now consists of what used to be the second element.

Answer (score 3):

You need to iterate **backward**

```
for (int i = messages.Count - 1; i >=0; i--)
{
    messages.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

Because in your current loop, you will be left with one time, if your list contains 3 items.

If you want to remove all items from your list then there is a method [`List<T>.RemoveAll Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

They're moved, [see MSDN on `List<T>.RemoveAt` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> When you call RemoveAt to remove an item, the **remaining items in the
>   list are renumbered** to replace the removed item. For example, if you
>   remove the item at index 3, the item at index 4 is moved to the 3
>   position.

To remove *all elements*, the [`Clear` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwb5h52a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Go thru reverse loop..

```
  for(int i = messages.Count - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
    messages.RemoveAt(i);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

.NET [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs#cf7f4095e4de7646) has following definition of RemoveAt method:

```
public void RemoveAt(int index) 
{
    if ((uint)index >= (uint)_size)             
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException();            
    Contract.EndContractBlock();

    _size--;

    if (index < _size) 
        Array.Copy(_items, index + 1, _items, index, _size - index);

    _items[_size] = default(T);
    _version++;
}
```

As you can see - if you remove item which is not last one copying of array items occurs (all items from index + 1 till the end are moved). So in your case its better to remove items from the end to avoid array copying on each iteration:

```
for (int i = messages.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    messages.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

Or simply call [`messages.Clear()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs#3d46113cc199059a) if you want to remove them all without additional logic - in that case internal array just cleared and size set to zero.

Answer (score 0):

You could just changes it to always delete the first one

```
List<string> messages = new List<string>();
messages.Add("a"); 
messages.Add("b");
messages.Add("c");

for (int i = 0; i < messages.Count; i++)
{
     messages.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

or to clear whole list in one statement

```
messages.Clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the other posts, you need to iterate backward

You've got many solutions to remove the items

```
messages.Clear();
```

or

```
while(messages.Count != 0){
    message.RemoveAt(0);
}
```